# Error compiling ffmpeg when avfilter is enabled

Tags: filter, cmake, ffmpeg, compiler-errors

I want to compile a C++ application that uses ffmpeg and I want to use filters.
I have set up a cmake file with :

```
set(FFMPEG_OPTIONS "-Wl,-no_compact_unwind -L/usr/local/lib" "-L/usr/lib" "-lbz2" "-liconv" "-lz" "-lavutil" "-lavcodec" "-lavdevice" "-lavformat" "-lavfilter" "-lswresample" "-lswscale" "-lx264" "-pthread" "-lm" "-framework AudioUnit" "-framework AudioToolbox" "-framework CoreAudio" "-framework VideoToolbox" "-framework CoreFoundation" "-framework CoreMedia" "-framework CoreVideo" "-framework CoreGraphics" "-framework CoreImage" "-framework CoreServices" "-framework Security" "-framework Foundation" "-framework AppKit")
target_link_libraries(main PUBLIC ${FFMPEG_OPTIONS})
```

But when I compile it gives the error :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_pp_free_context", referenced from:
      _pp_uninit in libavfilter.a(vf_pp.o)
  "_pp_free_mode", referenced from:
      _pp_uninit in libavfilter.a(vf_pp.o)
  "_pp_get_context", referenced from:
      _pp_config_props in libavfilter.a(vf_pp.o)
  "_pp_get_mode_by_name_and_quality", referenced from:
      _pp_init in libavfilter.a(vf_pp.o)
  "_pp_postprocess", referenced from:
      _pp_filter_frame in libavfilter.a(vf_pp.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

If I don't use filters it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `-lpostproc` to the libraries, they're in the same place as other FFmpeg libraries.